# Store trial usage values in registry or not

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, registry, store, trial

I have developed a Visual Basic.Net application and wish to have a limited usage of 15 times. Where is the best place to store the current usage times?

Is the registry the best place? I know that the user can just monitor the API calls to the registry and then can modify the value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to Store the Protection Trial Info for Software Protection Purpose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521468/where-to-store-the-protection-trial-info-for-software-protection-purpose)

Answer (score 0):

You could use encryption, perhaps. Also, if you do some Googling, you'll find that the consensus made by all programmers, is that there is no sure-fire way to protect against hackers etc. (especially when it comes to licensing/security/trials.

See my post on my licensing system.

I suggest storing it in several places, and not as a raw value (perhaps encrypted, compressed, hashed?), then check whether all stored values are equal (or even better still, add uo to a certain value, or when used in a calcualtion, equal a specified value. This is what I implemented.

Hope this helps :)